# Why my application doesnt support all devices in google play ?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-developer-api

My application doesnt support about 2000 devices . What is problem ? Is the gradle and manifest file suitable to support devices. For example HTC Desire 310 and HTC Wildfire doesnt support my application .

**gradle**

```
   minSdkVersion 10
    targetSdkVersion 22
```

**manifest.xml**

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
```

Comment: it is obvious ... what version of android has the Wildfire? does the Desire 310 has autofocus?

Comment: Hmm. yeah Right men. Thanks. :) . So, any other reason ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `<uses-feature>` & `<supports-screens>` to enable more device on google play.

*`<uses-feature>` declaration is to inform any external entity of the set of hardware and software features on which your application depends. The element offers a required attribute that lets you specify whether your application requires and cannot function without the declared feature, or whether it prefers to have the feature but can function without it. [read more](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html)*

make sure user these two attribute depends on your app requirement like if your app use camera but its not must require then use

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false"/>
```

*`<supports-screens>` An application "supports" a given screen size if it resizes properly to fill the entire screen. Normal resizing applied by the system works well for most applications and you don't have to do any extra work to make your application work on screens larger than a handset device.
make sure use both as per your requirement. [read more](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)*

support screen element for phone

```
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true" />
```

add `android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="720"` in above code if your app support tablets

Comment: @Selvin: have you ever try to upload app on Google play without supports-screens element? if not the try once & if yes then check how many device supported.

Comment: yes, i did - all devices are supported ... also it is stated in the documentation *When the either the android: minSdkVersion or android: targetSdkVersion is set to 4 or higher, the default for all attributes is "true". In this way, the application is considered to support all screen sizes by default.* + **Example 3**  *The manifest declares <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"> and does not include a <supports-screens> element. **Result: Google Play will show the app to all users, unless other filters apply.*** ...

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of reasons why a device is not able to download an app in google play. Some of those are:

- The device doesn't meet the minimum sdk specified in gradle.
- You have a `<uses-feature>` tag in your manifest and you set the "required" parameter as true. If the device doesn't have the required feature (e.g. NFC), then the app won't be available to the device.

There may be other reasons aside from these.
You might as well check if you specified a minimum sdk in both manifest and gradle, if that is the case, android will ignore the one declared in the manifest.